# how to control hushlogin behavior with systemd-logind?

Tags: systemd, login, logind

I am on `Ubuntu 18.04`, running the usual `systemd` setup. In particular, login is handled by `systemd-logind.service`.

If I add a `.hushlogin` file to my home directory, all output I usually receive during the `ssh` login is suppressed.

**My question:**

How do I control the name of the file playing the role that `.hushlogin` usually plays?

**Elaboration:**

I've grepped recursively for `hushlogin` and `HUSHLOGIN` in `/etc/` and `/lib/systemd/`, and found only three spots:

- The irrelevant `/etc/csh.login` (my users all use `bash`):

```
#
# Display global message-of-the-day:
#
if (! -e ~/.hushlogin ) then
   <blah>
endif
```

- `/etc/bash.bashrc` that *should* also be irrelevant, because I have local `~/.bashrc` files:

```
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
   <blah>
fi
```

- finally, the one spot that seems relevant: the file [/etc/login.defs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.defs.5.html).

```
HUSHLOGIN_FILE .hushlogin
#HUSHLOGIN_FILE  /etc/hushlogins
```

**What I've tried:**

- commenting out the `HUSHLOGIN_FILE .hushlogin` line
- replacing it with `HUSHLOGIN_FILE .boo`

I then restart `systemd-logind.service`. None of this has any effect: `.hushlogin` retains its chatter-suppression behavior, whereas my custom `.boo` never takes effect. This, regardless of whether I

- uncomment that second `HUSHLOGIN_FILE  /etc/hushlogins` line, or
- leave it commented.

So: what controls this behavior?

Comment: `fgrep -r hushlogin /sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/libexec/` can give a starting point.

Comment: Aha! Thanks: several files match: `/sbin/runuser`, `/bin/busybox`, `/usr/sbin/sshd` and `/usr/bin/lslogins`. But what then? These are all binary, but surely this must be configurable?